# Returning values from a text file as Strings

Tags: java, text, file-io, arraylist

Okay, so I've seen a few questions about this, but the answers were a bit overwhelming and quite varied. Obviously I'm looking for the simplest solution, but a want to be able to read in lines from a text file as strings and store them in an array list. I have an addItem(String item) method for each thing that would be imported to add it to the array list, but I don't know how to import the file correctly and have each line as an individual string.

Comment: How are the files formatted? purely just strings, are they delimited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like BufferedReader, which has functions for reading input from a file line by line.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("inputFile.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;

      while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null) {
          addItem(strLine);
      }

  } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my computer so I didn't compile this answer but I believe you are looking for somehing like this:

```
// file is your txt file.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // process the line, i.e, add to your list
}
br.close();
```

Hope it helps